# Calculating total time left and total time from a background worker OnProgressChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a background worker reporting the progress of the computation. It returns the current line number it is processing in the ProgressChangedEventArgs. I can from there determine the percentage done by doing

```
(int) (100 * (double)e.ProgressPercentage / csTextLines)
```

where csTextLines is the number of lines I am processing. The trouble I am running into is that I want to get a total estimated time and total time left also. There is nothing in background worker that I saw that would help me so I guess it has to be done with DateTime calculations. Here is what I have done so far to try and get TotalEstTime and TimeLeft

- TimeLeft = TotalEstTime - TimeSoFar;
- TotalEstTime = AvgTimeForEachLine * #OfLines;

Where

- TimeSoFar = DateTime.Now - m_startTime;
- AvgTimeForEachLine = (TimeFromLastLine + TotalTimeForAllLines) / #OfLines;

Where

- TimeFromLastLine = DateTime.Now - LastRecordedTime;
- TotalTimeForAllLines += TimeFromLastLine;

So if we turn this into code I have so far

```
// This event handler updates the progress. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan difInCalls = DateTime.Now.Subtract(m_LastProgressCall);
        m_LastProgressCall = DateTime.Now;
        m_totalDif = m_totalDif.Add(difInCalls);
        TimeSpan avgDif = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, ((int)m_totalDif.TotalMilliseconds / m_csNumLines));
        double totalTime = m_csNumLines * avgDif.TotalSeconds;
        double timeLeft = totalTime - (DateTime.Now.Subtract(m_Form2Start).TotalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("TotalEstTime: " + totalTime + " TimeLeft: " + timeLeft);


        // Update the progress label
        resultLabel.Text = "Line " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " of " + m_csNumLines + " at " + (int)(100 * (double)e.ProgressPercentage / m_csNumLines) + "% loaded";
    }
```

The problems that I am having are that my TotalTime grows significantly with how many lines are processed. In a 1437 line string it starts out at saying I have 1.4s and at the end it estimates 18.6s left. While actually taking 16.54s to complete.

My second problem is that the time left, does not really change. It fluctuates between about 1.1 and 2.5.

What could there be attributed to? What could be the problem?

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/x1CCceY7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're working off the last progress time, which will likely fluctuate as you go.  If you work from the starting time and the current time, and use the percentage complete, then you'll find that the time "self adjusts" as you move along.

For example, if you store `DateTime.Now` into a variable (such as `m_operationStart`, using your naming), you could write:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ProgressPercentage != 0)
  {
    double percentageComplete = (double)e.ProgressPercentage / m_csNumLines;

    TimeSpan timeSinceStart = DateTime.Now.Subtract(m_operationStart);
    TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeSinceStart.TotalMilliseconds / percentageComplete);
    TimeSpan timeLeft = totalTime - timeSinceStart;

    Console.WriteLine("TotalEstTime: " + totalTime + " TimeLeft: " + timeLeft);


    // Update the progress label
    resultLabel.Text = "Line " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " of " + m_csNumLines + " at " + (int)(100.0 * percentageComplete) + "% loaded";
  }
  else
    resultLabel.Text = "Line " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " of " + m_csNumLines;
}
```

Comment: This code makes sense when I read it over, but whenever I try to execute the code I get a OverFlow exception. It is just when calculating the TotalTime.

Comment: @user1596244 This should work - the ticks was overflowing since the numbers (in your case) were too large.  I believe using Milliseconds should work fine, though.

Comment: Still overflowing, Ill try seconds.. -- edit I tried seconds and it too overflowed.

Comment: Yeah it overflows with ticks, milliseconds, and seconds, and minutes.

Comment: @user1596244 Even with the percentage not including the *100?  Interesting.  What values are you getting for your timespans and percenatages?

Comment: @user1596244 Something else is going on, then - because this works fine: `TimeSpan timeSinceStart = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:15.0150484"); double percentage = 0.955462769659012; TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeSinceStart.TotalMilliseconds / percentage);`

Comment: @user1596244 Ahh - need to check for that case specifically - makes sense - will edit  (I had assumed falsely you were passing "line 1" for first line, not 0, given the labels, etc)